# React Big Calendar - Custom Popup

Tags: reactjs, popup, react-big-calendar

I want to create my own popup for react big calendar when I click on **more** text.

[image: more text]

React big calendar has **onShowMore** function but, It'll redirect to day view when I disable default popup.(`popup={false}`)

check it out on here,
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-example-lrwm4?file=/index.js

can you give me a possible solution for this ?

Update,
I'm using custom tool bar and in order to use it I have to use **onView**. this function will redirect to the day view. need to prevent redirection from here.

Answer (score 0):

We have an available prop to disable redirection:

```
<Calendar
    ...
    popup={false}
    ...
    doShowMoreDrillDown={false}
    defaultView={Views.MONTH}
    ...
    views={['month']} />
```

It is `doShowMoreDrillDown` which is the prop you need. It is not a hack, so it stops redirection properly.

This was added as a response to library issue [#1850](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/pull/1850).

Answer (score -1):

Okay so to prevent the redirection to the day view, keep the
**popup={true}**
but add this to the onShowMore prop:

```
onShowMore={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }}
```

This will prevent the redirection.
You can check out the working example of it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-edison-rsfzpm?file=/index.js

Answer (score -4):

Use `popup={true}` instead of `false`.